# Add numpy array elements/slices with same bin assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram, binning

I have some array `A`, and the corresponding elements of the array `bins` contain each row's bin assignment. I want to construct an array `S`, such that

```
S[0, :] = (A[(bins == 0), :]).sum(axis=0)
```

This is rather easy to do with `np.stack` and list comprehensions, but it seems overly complicated and not terribly readable. Is there a more general way to sum (or even apply some general function to) slices of arrays with bin assignments? `scipy.stats.binned_statistic` is along the right lines, but requires that bin assignments and values to compute the functions on are the same shape (since I am using slices, this is not the case).

For example, if

```
A = np.array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
              [2., 3., 4., 5.],
              [9., 8., 7., 6.],
              [8., 7., 6., 5.]])
```

and

```
bins = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

then it should result in

```
S = np.array([[10., 10., 10., 10.],
              [2.,  3.,  4.,  5. ],
              [8.,  7.,  6.,  5. ]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `matrix-multiplication` using [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) -

```
(bins == np.arange(bins.max()+1)[:,None]).dot(A)
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: A = np.array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
    ...:               [2., 3., 4., 5.],
    ...:               [9., 8., 7., 6.],
    ...:               [8., 7., 6., 5.]])

In [41]: bins = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])

In [42]: (bins == np.arange(bins.max()+1)[:,None]).dot(A)
Out[42]: 
array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
       [  2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  8.,   7.,   6.,   5.]])
```

**Performance boost**

A more efficient way to create the mask `(bins == np.arange(bins.max()+1)[:,None])`, would be like so -

```
mask = np.zeros((bins.max()+1, len(bins)), dtype=bool)
mask[bins, np.arange(len(bins))] = 1
```

Comment: This is about 30% faster than @Psidom's solution, so accepting this. It's slightly more straight-forward to me, but both work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.add.reduceat`:

```
import numpy as np
# index to sort the bins
sort_index = bins.argsort()

# indices where the array needs to be split at
indices = np.concatenate(([0], np.where(np.diff(bins[sort_index]))[0] + 1))

# sum values where the bins are the same
np.add.reduceat(A[sort_index], indices, axis=0)

# array([[ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
#        [  2.,   3.,   4.,   5.],
#        [  8.,   7.,   6.,   5.]])
```